# Why did the ZX Spectrum use an internal speaker?

Tags: zx-spectrum, sound

I was surprised to note recently that the Sinclair ZX Spectrum used an internal speaker. I knew the BBC Micro used one, presumably because it was designed to be optionally used with a monitor which likely would not supply one, but as far as I know, the ZX Spectrum was always used with a TV set.

Given that Sinclair designs were very heavily optimized for cost, why did the Spectrum go with an internal speaker instead of just using the one in the TV set and saving a small amount of money?

Comment: Did any computer used with a TV-set use the TV for sound?

Comment: @UncleBod TI 99/4, Atari 400/800, Commodore VIC, C64, C16, Tandy CoCo, MSX - pick your favorite. Eventually the majority of home computers did. The Apple II is a notable exception, but then again, it's a whole generation before home computers came.

Comment: All *Sinclair* computers had a built-in (very cheap) speaker, even the QL (arguably, it needed one, as it was intended for use with a video monitor) and the Cambridge Z88

Comment: The ZX Spectrum issue 1 schematics show a composite video out option. This might be a very simple reason. https://spectrumforeveryone.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/ZXSpectrumIssue12-Schematics.pdf

Comment: @tofro - not all Sinclair computers had a built-in speaker.  Specifically, neither ZX80 nor ZX81 had any support for sound.

Comment: @TobySpeight thta is why they had neither an in-built speaker nor sound via RF

Comment: @tofro, so you're willing to retract your claim that "*All Sinclair computers had a built-in (very cheap) speaker*", then?

Comment: @TobySpeight If it makes you happy...

Comment: I am now curious...
Did it also have an audio output?

Comment: I remember one of the magazines ("ZX User" or "Your Sinclair" or something like that) had a program which would cause a ZX80 to play sounds.  I never knew if it was an April Fool's joke.  It's true that old microcomputers make a faint humming sound and you can change it by executing different instructions in a tight loop.

Comment: You can definitely use the tape output to create sound on a ZX80 and ZX81. It's in no way different from the original ZX Spectrum's "sound generator" hardware. Just connect earphones and toggle the cassette port.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I strongly expect that an RF modulator, which is needed to create the TV-style signal, would cost more if it had to handle sound too. A small speaker is very cheap, and often a useful device for debugging a circuit board or firmware.

The Spectrum 128K+ did make sound output through the TV, and also had much more sophisticated sound hardware, with an [AY-3-8910](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_AY-3-8910) sound chip.

Comment: This is almost certainly it - Sinclair corp's entire modus operandi was to produce a computer as cheaply as possible, to get as many of them out the door as they could at the lowest price imaginable. Their computers cost £50; by comparison the Commodore VIC-20 cost £150 and the BBC Micro cost £235-£335.

Comment: Besides the price, could it be because of video interference, and needing a better modulator to handle that?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Possibly, but I don't know either way.

Comment: @Rui - that still comes down to price in the end (more expensive modulator vs cheap internal buzzer).

Comment: The BBC Micro had an internal speaker too, and was equally incapable of playing sounds via a television set.  (Though you did get some cool squeaks and blips if you turned up the volume and then poked random bytes into the video control registers.)  I think the UHF modulator hardware just didn't have support for sound, and it wasn't cheap to add it.

Comment: @EdAvis correct, plus the BBC Micro was aimed at both home and school use, with the expectation that schools have monitors while homes have TVs, and you couldn't send sound to a monitor, so the BBC Micro *had* to have an internal speaker for the school / monitor use-case.  So, given that this speaker was going to be supplied anyway, and there were only square-wave oscillators, there wasn't much point in *also* adding a component to send the same sound to the TV, unless somebody wanted to record a program's output with a VCR which was probably considered too unlikely to be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 21):

Always hard to guess why something simple hasn't been done.

In case of the Spectrum it might have been to save on component price. The modulator used is the same as for the ZX81, so Sinclair was for sure already at the optimum price point. On the down side it's a simple video modulator (*1) without a mixing stage for sound, after all, in its quest of maximum reduction the ZX80/81 did skip sound as well. Next to all other home computers (*2) of that era had sound and used the TV set. Without sound not only the sound circuit could be saved (*3), but more important money was saved on the modulator.

Sinclair could have voted to use a modulator capable of adding sound to the Spectrum, but buying them would have started at a higher price point due lower (start) volume - or to add a cheap speaker on board and share buying power for components with ZX-81 production.

---

*1 - In fact it's so simple, that they already had to add quite some analogue gears to make it work.

*2 - TI 99/4, Atari 400/800, Commodore VIC, C64, C16, Tandy CoCo, MSX (pick your favorite), eventually the majority of home computers did. The Apple II is a notable exception, but then again, it's a whole generation before home computers came.

*3 - Not much, as this could have been done with a single signal pin and maybe a driver transistor.

Comment: Its probably worth pointing out that the ZX81 used a video-only modulator because it has no sound output whatsoever, just to make your point more clear.

Comment: I've just checked in its old advanced manual: my Oric Atmos definitely had a speaker. And it had very good sound compared to Spectrums and similar (using AY3-8912). And it could output to a standalone amplifier, too.

Comment: If one didn't mind require users to adjust the "fine-tuning knob" on their sets, one could get by with a really crummy RF modulator that doesn't use any particularly-high-precision components, but the optimal knob position for the best picture would often differ from that required for best sound.  I'd guess that the component tolerances to produce a usable picture could be sloppier than those that would be  needed if the sound had to be usable simultaneously.

Comment: I remember reading in ZX User magazine of a program that played sound on a ZX80.  I didn't check if it was the April issue.

Answer (score 11):

Because of different TV sound IF frequencies around the world, modulating the sound on a subcarrier would mean different modulators would be needed in different regions. An internal speaker is cheaper and reduces the chances of sending the wrong unit to a different region.

Comment: Do you have a source on that? As far as I can see, PAL (which is the system the Spectrum was first made for) have the same spectrum _per channel_ all the time. If you change to SECAM or NTSC you would anyway have to adjust the hardware in some way (sometimes a simple switch, sometimes it was a completely different hardware) to get a picture.

Comment: @UncleBod See the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL#PAL_broadcast_systems, particularly "Vision/Sound carrier spacing", which shows that the UK has a different sound subcarrier to the rest of Europe.

Comment: Uk was 6MHz and other regions @4.5, 5.0 or 5.5MHz. Modulators were tunable to tweak sound IF during final testing, but time costs money. Cheaper to use a different component.

Comment: @UncleBod Your comment brings bad flashbacks from the early 90's. Poland switched from SECAM to PAL so people imported PAL TVs and VCRs en masse and many ended up with no sound because of the dreaded "b/g vs d/k" problem.

Comment: @Agent_L I had the same problem when I came to the UK and suddenly the sound on my playstation would not come through the TV.